# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'NULL'

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x

When I run python manage.py migrate on my file, this ValueError shows up.

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, cms, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying cms.0002_auto_20170401_2307...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\sndys\project\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\sndys\project\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\sndys\project\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\sndys\project\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\sndys\project\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Users\sndys\project\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\sndys\project\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\sndys\project\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\sndys\project\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\sndys\project\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 84, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "C:\Users\sndys\project\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 231, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_fields=[field])
  File "C:\Users\sndys\project\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 113, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(field)
  File "C:\Users\sndys\project\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 221, in effective_default
    default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\sndys\project\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 909, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.target_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)
  File "C:\Users\sndys\project\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 755, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "C:\Users\sndys\project\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 938, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Users\sndys\project\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 946, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'NULL'
```

My models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import markdown

# Create your models here.
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Image(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    alt_text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Gallery(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    images = models.ManyToManyField(Image)
    description = models.TextField()
    layout = models.CharField(
        max_length=5,
        choices=(
            ('LINK', 'Linked'),
            ('HORI', 'Horizontal'),
            ('VERT', 'Vertical')))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content = models.TextField()
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    edit_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    featured_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    publish_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    @property
    def content_html(self):
        return markdown.markdown(self.content)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Articles'
        ordering = ['creation_date']`enter code here`
```

When I did python manage.py makemigrations, this showed up:

You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'category' to article without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:

1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)

2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py

Select an option:

I selected 1 and gave the default value "NULL" and I think this is the mistake I may have made. After this "python manage.py makemigrations" ran successfully but "python manage.py migrate" is giving an error.
After this I tried to give the category foreign key in Article class a default value = 1 but same error occurs on migrate.

Can anyone tell me where is the problem and how to fix it.

Comment: Delete your latest migration file. Provide default value in your models.py file and run `python manage.py makemigrations` again.

Comment: You can make your foreign key nullable temporarily by setting `null=True`, then migrate and insert appropriate values for your foreign key. Then remove `null=True` and migrate again.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't supposed to give the value you want the DB to receive. You give the value in Python. However you would only get that message if null=True wasn't set on the field. Delete the migration and set null=True on the field.